# How to add FORWARD button in iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

In a master detail, there is a "back" button present when looking at the details, but how do I add a "forward" button?  Tapping on it takes the user to the next record/detail.[TableView example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFwUK.png)

Tapping on the ">", will take take the user to the "kate bell".  The work around would be to go to "all contacts", and then tap on "kate bell"

I am unfamiliar with Obj-C, and I am learning swift.

I wrote this in swift.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem( title: "Next", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "next") 

@IBAction func next () { }
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by detail? A viewcontroller or some image or something.

Comment: In a navigation controller? What knows about the order? Tell us about your data. Do you even need multiple view controllers or really just a horizontal collection view you can scroll?

Comment: Are you really asking about having "next" and "previous" buttons on the detail screen?

Comment: That back button usually doesn't load the previous item in the table, but brings you back to the table itself. Take a look at the Navigation Controllers docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The rows (UITableView) will have list of 250 chapters.  Tapping on a chapter will take it to the text/images/audio.  To go to the next chapter, tap ">" - I've added a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will add an item to the right side of the navigation bar, and call the `-forwardAction:` method when tapped;

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(forwardAction:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
    // ...
}

-(IBAction)forwardAction:(id)sender {}
```

Comment: I wrote this in swift.  navigationItem.rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem( title: "Next", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "next")